# Checking size of allocated memory

Tags: c, dynamic-allocation

I'm writing a program which accepts the size of an array as an argument which should then dynamically allocate memory for that size.

I want my program to return the size of the memory which was allocated.
Currently I'm using `argv` to read the input value and then `mmap` for the dynamic allocation. I also use a for loop to display what number is saved in each index of the array.

I know allocating could be done with `malloc`, but I'm not able to use it.
I guess I need to start at the last element and check all cells until I get a SEGFAULT signal.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: 
Short code without libraries etc...

```
input = (atoi(argv[1]));
int* arr = mmap(0, input, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);

for (i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    arr[i] = i + 1; 
}
```

Comment: why arent u able to use malloc?

Comment: "check all cells untill I get SEGFAULT". That looks very dodgy to me. How can you guarantee a SEGFAULT?

Comment: @CherubimAnand Editted.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is no crash at the moment, I get all the values, but I don't know how to get size of allocated mem.

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy I guess I could check all the cells in 'array' for last to first, and than when i get SEGFAULT I know I reach the memory which is not allocated to me? But that was just my guess.

Comment: The length will be the length you asked for (`input`), unless this couldn't be satisfied, in which case it will return `MAP_FAILED` (=-1).

Comment: @TripeHound How to check how much memory it costs for like 5 int numbers?

Comment: Note that the SEGFAULT will only occur after you try to access a page that does not belong to you. It does not have fine enough resolution to stop at a byte. This assumption would break when, for example, two memory allocations used nearby chunks of memory, which is perfectly valid.

Comment: You would then think that the whole page was allocated for your array and would end up overwriting the other allocation, or worse, some of its metadata used by `free()` and friends.

Comment: XY problem and very wrong approach. Not clear what you try to solve, but provoking undefined behaviour is definitively wrong. It's like trying to find electrical wires in a wall by hammering nails into the wall until you get sparks. Don't follow that path any further! What is the problem allocationg the memory with `malloc`? You should provide more details and a [mcve].

Comment: @F.Mark the _actual_ size of memory allocated by `malloc` in bytes is the number you provided as parameter to `malloc` plus  a certain non specified number of bytes used for internal bookkeeping by the memory manager (typically 8 to 16 bytes or so). But I'm still not sure what you actually are asking or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm not using malloc.

Comment: @F.Mark but you should. Why do you need to use `mmap`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Answered below.

Comment: You should check the return value from `mmap()`.  You should show how you set `fd` — when using MAP_ANONYMOUS, the value should be `-1` for maximum portability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't check the amount of allocated space in C or check the size of arrays. You need to save it as a variable explicitly by yourself.

Comment: So using mmap I can't check how much memory was allocated? Beter void using mmap? Or is possible to solve this using mmap?

Comment: @F.Mark `mmap` or `malloc` the problem is the same. When you allocate memory _you_ know how much you did allocate, just keep track of that number. That's it. Period.

Comment: @MichaelWalz So this could be solved by storing the default size of memory and than compare it with the size after allocating? Because I want my program to print out like "You allocated 5MB of memory".

Comment: @F.Mark I don't understand your question. The quantity of memory allocated is in the `input` variable. What do you mean by _default size of memory_ ? There is no such thing.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, if I input 5, than what would be stored in array? 1, 2, 3, 4, 5? If yes, than I want to know how much MB is that, or I want my program to display how much memory was allocated to it.

Comment: For mmap, there's /proc/self/maps but I can't think of a situation when parsing it would be preferable to just saving the size somewhere.

Comment: @F.Mark If you input 5, you've just allocated 5 bytes, which is roughly 0.000005 MB. What you store in the array doesn't matter for the size

Comment: @F.Mark (forget about `mmap`, you need `malloc`). If your input is 5 (for storing 5 `int`s) and you use `int* arr = malloc(input * sizeof (int));` the system allocates 20 bytes (assuming 32 bit ints) plus an undetermined (but small) number of  bytes for of bookkepping.

Comment: @pi_pi3 So if I input 2^8 elements, than I allocated 256 bytes?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well that exactly is the problem. I know how to use malloc, because we have been learning this for the past month. But now we are at mmap and working with it.

Comment: @F.Mark you mmap `input` bytes. So I suppose the _actual_ size used size is `input` rounded up the the next page boudary (typically 4K), but who cares ?. Still not sure what your actual problem is.

Comment: @MichaelWalz So if I input 100 then I mmaped 100 bytes? The problem is I should input the size of array and than my program should return how much memory was allocated.

Comment: @F.Mark sorry, I'dont get what your _actual_ problem is, nor did anybody else who was dealing your question. I'm giving up.

Comment: @F.Mark If you input 100, then you've mmaped 100 bytes. An int is 4 bytes wide, so you're gonna have to multiply your input by 4, or rather sizeof(int) to be portable.
    int* arr = mmap(0, input*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);

Answer (score -3):

```c
#include <malloc.h>

printf("size in bytes %u\n", malloc_usable_size(*ptr));
```

Comment: You probably ought to mention which C standard defines this function.  I couldn't find it in the C23 draft.  It's also unclear how this relates to memory mapped with `mmap()`.